# <base> href always points to homepage

Tags: joomla-3.3.x, templates, sef

Having a strange issue with J3.3.6. The `<base>` tag `href` is always pointing to the root / homepage of my name, e.g www.example.com, even when on an inner page. I only noticed when trying to use an anchor, and the anchor used the base href and linked to the homepage.

I haven't come across this issue with any other sites I've built on 3.3.6, and as far as I can tell there aren't any other differences. I've tried:

- Resetting .htaccess to the J! default (I added in a few cache control headers - no change)
- Switching off SEF URLs (see below)
- Checking $live_site in configuration.php (no value set)

When I switch off SEF URLs and URL re-writing, the base href is disappears (only the canonical link remains, which is correct).

If I edit `/libraries/joomla/html/document/renderer/head.php`, around line 74 - 76 to use `JURI::current()` instead of `$document->getBase();` then the correct URLs at used in the base value **if SEF URLs are enabled** - but I've never had to do this before and obviously this will be wiped on upgrade. If SEF URLs are off this is wrong as it just goes to index.php without any query parameters, causing the same sort of issue in reverse (anchors all go to the homepage).

Answer (score 1):

That is the whole point of the `<base>` tag. It's supposed to point to the root of your website which makes using relative link easier, and with Joomla, this gets automatically added to the `<head>` by the following code snippet:

```
<jdoc:include type="head" />
```

I'm not sure how your anchors are setup but if you use the following for example:

```
<a href="#section">anchor</a>

<div id="section">
    <p>content here</p>
</div>
```

Then upon clicking the anchor, it will take you to the `#section` ID

If this doesn't work, then it might be something that your template is doing. Try changing the template to the default Protostar one and see if you have the same issue.

Comment: Fundamental misunderstand of the base tag on my part there. Thanks for this - going to have a quick look at some docs...

Comment: Weird, then, on the throwaway site I set up it's now setting the `base` as the full URL. Hm.

Comment: Wooops or not. I'm off for coffee and a cry.

Comment: In HTML, the `<a>` tag has no `name` attribute. You should be using `href` as shown ;)

Comment: It's all gone horribly, horribly wrong this morning :(

Comment: Still seeing issues with `<a href='#link'>Link</a>` teamed with `<a id='link'></a>` not playing ball and going to homepage with base href is set to root. Bahrgh.

Comment: Would you be able to provide a link to your site and also mention where the anchor is and where is supposed to link to?